# Set Path for Mounted Network Drive in Node

Tags: node.js, networking, fs

I am trying to write to a mapped network drive in Node using the `windows-network-drive` module and the `fs` module.

```
networkDrive.mount('\\\\server', 'Z', 'username', 'password')
  .then(driveLetter => {

  let filePath;

  filePath = path.join(driveLetter + ":\\path\\to\\directory", "message.txt");

  fs.writeFile(filePath, "text", (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The file has been saved!');
  });
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
});
```

How can I get the connection and path to write to a remote location?

Do I need to pass in the drive letter?  If so, how do I locate it?

> (node:4796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   ChildProcessError: Command failed: net use Z: "\server" /P:Yes /user:username password
>   System error 67 has occurred.
>
> The network name cannot be found.
>
> `net use Z: "\server" /P:Yes /user:username password` (exited with error code 2)
>   at callback (C:\app\location\node_modules\child-process-promise\lib\index.js:33:27)
>   at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:279:5)
>   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
>   at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
>   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
>   name: 'ChildProcessError',
>   code: 2,
>   childProcess:
>
> { ChildProcess: { [Function: ChildProcess] super_: [Function] },
>   fork: [Function],
>   _forkChild: [Function],
>   exec: [Function],
>   execFile: [Function],
>   spawn: [Function],
>   spawnSync: [Function: spawnSync],
>   execFileSync: [Function: execFileSync],
>   execSync: [Function: execSync] },
>   stdout: '',
>   stderr: 'System error 67 has occurred.\r\n\r\nThe network name cannot be found.\r\n\r\n' }

P.S. this code logs Z

```
networkDrive.mount('\\\\server\\path\\to\\directory', 'Z', 'mdadmin', 'Password1!')
  .then(function (driveLetter) {
    console.log(driveLetter);
    fs.writeFile('L_test.txt', 'list', (err) => {
      if (err) throw err
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write from a REST Service hosted in IIS, you will need to properly set the permissions on the server.

> 1. You will need to set the identity of the Application Pool of your site.

[image]

> 2. You will need to grant write permissions to match that account or account group to the folder that you are trying to write to.

Note: If you map a folder to a network drive letter through the OS, it is only defined at the user account level.

[image]

> 3. So, if you have mapped the folder location to a drive letter (in this case 'X:'), instead of writing to

```
fs.writeFile('X:/test.txt', 'text', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err
})
```

You must write to to full path

```
fs.writeFile('\\\\servername\\path\\to\\director\\test.txt', 'text', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err
})
```

Note: Backslashes need to be escaped, so the Windows file system will show something like `\\servername\path\to\directory`.

P.S. This answer includes recommendations from users l-bahr and Ctznkane525.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what error you got, so here are a couple tips for when you are using [windows-network-drive.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-network-drive)

**Escape Special Characters**

Windows uses \ to separate directories. [\ is a special character](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) in a JavaScript string and must be escaped like this \\. e.g. C:\file.txt would be C:\\file.txt in a string.

**Use POSIX Separation Character When You Can**

Because of the added difficulty in reading a path with the escaped \, I would recommend using / instead. windows-network-drive should handle both just fine. e.g. C:\file.txt would be C:/file.txt in a string.

**Example**

I tried to make this match your example, but made a few changes so that it will work on any windows machine.

```
let networkDrive = require("windows-network-drive");

/**
 * https://github.com/larrybahr/windows-network-drive
 * Mount the local C: as Z:
 */
networkDrive.mount("\\\\localhost\\c$", "Z", undefined, undefined)
    .then(function (driveLetter)
    {
        const fs = require("fs");
        const path = require("path");
        let filePath;

        /**
         * This will create a file at "Z:\message.txt" with the contents of "text"
         * NOTE: Make sure to escape '\' (e.g. "\\" will translate to "\")
         */
        filePath = path.join(driveLetter + ":\\", "message.txt");
        fs.writeFile(filePath, "text", (err) =>
        {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('The file has been saved!');
        });
    });
```

Comment: OK. I updated the question to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: How would I access the path of a drive that is already mounted?

Comment: Look at the find method. I'll post an example later today, but the idea should be that you use find to see if the driver is mounted. If it is not them you mount it. Both will give you the ability to get a drive letter. From there write your file like I did in the example. From your error log it looks like you don't have the correct number of starting slashes. It should read ... Z: "\\server" /P... Instead of \server

Comment: I can write files when running a unit test script, but am having problems running it on the REST server.  I may be running into a problem with Windows IIS.

Comment: I have added an [example](https://github.com/larrybahr/windows-network-drive/tree/master/example/write-a-file-to-a-network-drive) to the project that may help. If you are still having an issue, update your question with the real code and the error you are getting. In your last update it looked like the drive was mounting. As long as you have permissions you should be able to use fs to write the file.

Comment: So if a network drive is mounted to ```X:```, you would point to ```//localhost/x$```?

Comment: No. In my example //localhost/c$ would be replaced with your //server/path/to/directory. Once you have a drive letter (In your case X) you can do "X:/message.txt". If you post the code and the error, it may be easier to help. If you have a drive letter then the drive is mounted and the library did what it should. Try to mount the drive and on that same PC try to create the file through windows explorer. You may not have permissions.